# Split array into sub arrays kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have an array like [Sunday, monday, sunday, tuesday, monday, monday, wednesday, friday, wednesday]

I want sub arrays like `[sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday] [sunday,monday,wednesday] [monday, wednesday]`

can anyone suggest how to solve this

I tried, groupby and distinct but did not get any desired results

Comment: What is your grouping criteria?

Comment: Initial array has 2 wednesdays and 1 friday; resulting sub arrays have 3 wednesdays and 0 fridays.

Comment: How `[sunday, friday, sunday, monday]` should be splitted? As `[[sunday, friday],[sunday, monday]]` or `[[sunday, friday, monday], [sunday]]` or `[[sunday, monday, friday], [sunday]]`?